How to correctly load ag-Grid CSS in an older Node.js 10.16.3 project using Polymer and Webpack?
I'm working on an older project using Node.js 10.16.3 and Polymer. I want to integrate the ag-Grid library, but I'm facing issues due to compatibility problems with modern JavaScript syntax, specifically the "??" operator, which isn't supported in my Node version. I am not using any front-end framework.
To work around this, I decided to include the ag-Grid library in my Handlebars index.hbs file like this:
<script src="scripts/ext/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ag-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ag-theme-quartz.css" />

I'm using Webpack to build the project and have configured CopyWebpackPlugin to handle the necessary files:
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { 
    from: resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js'),
    to: './scripts/ext',
    flatten: true
  }, 
  {
    from: resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'),
    to: './styles/'
  },
  {
    from: resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css'),
    to: './styles/'
  }
]);

This is the result: ag grid without css
The JavaScript file is working correctly, and all data loads as expected. However, the CSS files are not being applied at all. I've even tried hardcoding the CSS directly into the style tag of my component, but this didn't solve the problem either.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide advice on how to correctly load and apply ag-Grid CSS in this setup?
